# CommonJS syntax with rollup

Tags: javascript, commonjs, rollup, rollupjs

I'm working on a lightweight rollup config. For some reason CommonJS aren't converted in the output while ES Modules do.

I'm using both `resolve` and `commonjs` rollup plugins.

```js
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';


module.exports = {
  input: 'static/js/script.js',
  output: {
    file: '_site/static/js/script.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    terser(),
  ]
};
```

```js
import { cube } from './components/component-1.js';
import { foo } from './components/component-2.js';
const camelCase = require('camelcase');

console.log(cube(3));
console.log(foo);
console.log(camelCase('foo-bar'));
```

This **works**:

```js
import camelCase from 'camelcase';
```

But CommonJS **doesn't work**:

```js
const camelCase = require('camelcase');
```

Do I need to pass any other configuration to make CommonJS syntax work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix and match `require` and `import` with rollup-plugin-commonjs. If a module contains `import` it's treated as ESM, and `require` is left untouched.